# How to filter a regex (exclude special characters)

Tags: regex

Let's say that I need to filter all my files' names that don't include special characters.

```
ASDA123fasf - would pass
asasdasd*dasd - wouldn't pass
```

Comment: What exactly are non-special characters? Only letters? Numbers? "Simple" symbols like minus or underscore?

Comment: Yes, the regex should filter only files' names that have letters and digits in it

Comment: You could start by trying something like `find FOLDER/ -iregex '.*/[a-z0-9.]*'`. Note the beginning `.*/` in the pattern, because `-iregex` matches against the whole path, not just the file name,  and also that I added a `.` tot he allowed characters inside the square brackets, so that it still will match files with extensions. You might want to remove that one depending on your goals. The match is case-insensitive.

Comment: No, they shouldn't @dsstorefile1 Anyway, is there a grep solution? #Byte Commander

Comment: What do you mean by "filter", exactly? Can you give a simple use case (i.e. what are you going to apply the expression **to**, and what are you going to do with the result)?

Comment: Already said. Imagine I do `ls` and I want to get only names of the folders with letters and digits. `ASAS23123fasf` would pass, `123123fasf` would pass aswell but `asdads&*!@213` shouldn't pass

Comment: Use `find`. The output of `ls` is meant for human eyes and not to be parsed. While you *could* theoretically tape something together like `ls | grep -i '[a-z0-9.]*'`, that would be bad practice and not reliable for some cases.

Comment: With bash extended globbing (`shopt -s extglob` - although it should be enabled by default) `ls *([[:alnum:]])` will list files whose names are alphanumeric

Answer (score 0):

One of many alternatives would be `find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*/[a-z0-9.]*' -ls`

If you think you may need to use this often, you could even create an alias to shorten the command:

**Note:** The below alias will only work in the current directory, although you could easily create a script that would parse a command line argument for the directory..

```
alias myls="find . -maxdepth 1 -iregex '.*/[a-z0-9.]*' -ls"
```

If you were to do that, every time you issued the command `myls` you'd get the desired output without all the extra typing. Lazy or efficient, you decide.

Sources:
[Byte Commander comment here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038172/how-to-filter-a-regex-exclude-special-characters/1038186#comment1690205_1038172)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509624/how-to-limit-depth-for-recursive-file-list - specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25618630/3816360)

`man find`